# Webcam, Bluetooth, USB devices stop working after waking from suspend

Tags: bluetooth, suspend, webcam, 21.10, 22.04

I am using a laptop with Kubuntu 22.04 (Kernel 5.15.0-27-generic).

I had this same problem previously on Kubuntu 21.10 as well.
Every time the laptop wakes up from suspend, the webcam stops working.
Also, bluetooth adapter shows `No Bluetooth Adapters Found` and the connected USB keyboard and mouse also stops working.
I have to reboot the system to get the running again.
Opening Cheese shows `No Device Found`

Is there a fix for this issue?

Comment: You can intervene in the Suspend/Resume and Hibernate/Wake processes. `sudo apt-install pm-tools;dpkg -L pm-tools` and read. Look at the startup logs to start figuring out how your devices are initialized with `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.